# gatsby transformer sharp createSchemaCustomization breaking digitalocean build

Tags: javascript, deployment, gatsby, digital-ocean

good day. Im having an issue when deploying to digitalocean a gatsby app.

Im getting the following error:

```
ERROR #11321  PLUGIN
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.123576271Z] 
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.123581789Z] "gatsby-transformer-sharp" threw an error while running the
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.123588327Z] createSchemaCustomization lifecycle:
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.123592428Z] 
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.123597195Z] Expected undefined to be a GraphQL nullable type.
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.123602440Z] 

[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217730653Z] 
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217738299Z]   Error: Expected undefined to be a GraphQL nullable type.
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217744559Z]   
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217748772Z]   - customize-schema.js:485 imageNodeType
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217755236Z]     [workspace]/[gatsby-transformer-sharp]/customize-schema.js:485:11
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217762490Z]   
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217767037Z]   - customize-schema.js:644 createFields
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217773273Z]     [workspace]/[gatsby-transformer-sharp]/customize-schema.js:644:21
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217777358Z]   
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217787660Z]   - customize-schema.js:840 Object.module.exports [as createSchemaCustomization]
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217794900Z]     [workspace]/[gatsby-transformer-sharp]/customize-schema.js:840:13
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217800428Z]   
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217804562Z]   - api-runner-node.js:434 runAPI
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217809280Z]     [workspace]/[gatsby]/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:434:22
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217815532Z]   
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217820057Z]   - api-runner-node.js:585 Promise.catch.decorateEvent.pluginName
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217839308Z]     [workspace]/[gatsby]/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:585:13
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217843813Z]   
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217847462Z]   - debuggability.js:384 Promise._execute
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217852580Z]     [workspace]/[bluebird]/js/release/debuggability.js:384:9
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217856512Z]   
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217860339Z]   - promise.js:518 Promise._resolveFromExecutor
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217864704Z]     [workspace]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:518:18
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217868697Z]   
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217872694Z]   - promise.js:103 new Promise
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217876610Z]     [workspace]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:103:10
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217880177Z]   
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217883861Z]   - api-runner-node.js:583 
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217887975Z]     [workspace]/[gatsby]/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:583:16
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217892211Z]   
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217896077Z]   - util.js:16 tryCatcher
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217899976Z]     [workspace]/[bluebird]/js/release/util.js:16:23
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217905006Z]   
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217909323Z]   - reduce.js:166 Object.gotValue
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217913111Z]     [workspace]/[bluebird]/js/release/reduce.js:166:18
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217917332Z]   
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217921320Z]   - reduce.js:155 Object.gotAccum
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217925787Z]     [workspace]/[bluebird]/js/release/reduce.js:155:25
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217929725Z]   
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217933984Z]   - util.js:16 Object.tryCatcher
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217938317Z]     [workspace]/[bluebird]/js/release/util.js:16:23
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217942371Z]   
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217946448Z]   - promise.js:547 Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217951069Z]     [workspace]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:547:31
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217954599Z]   
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.217958163Z] 
not finished createSchemaCustomization - 0.226s
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.222876144Z] 
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.479376150Z] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.480113743Z] npm ERR! errno 1
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.487270336Z] npm ERR! gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 build: `gatsby build`
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.487288402Z] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.487293527Z] npm ERR! 
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.487661112Z] npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 build script.
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.487672333Z] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.500625147Z] 
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.500829047Z] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.501066886Z] npm ERR!     /home/apps/.npm/_logs/2021-05-04T15_49_08_487Z-debug.log
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.527093479Z] building: exit status 1
[2021-05-04T15:49:08.533964962Z] ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
[2021-05-04T15:49:28.222787831Z] /.app_platform/util.sh: line 154: printf: write error: Is a directory
[2021-05-04T15:49:28.233541353Z] cat: /.app_platform/.tmp/tmp.AEZAXCruwm: Is a directory
[2021-05-04T15:49:28.410022555Z] 
[2021-05-04T15:49:28.410147916Z] For documentation on the buildpacks used to build your app, please see:
[2021-05-04T15:49:28.410358291Z]    Node.js: https://do.co/apps-buildpack-node
[2021-05-04T15:49:28.411740813Z] 
[2021-05-04T15:49:28.412169311Z]  ! Build failed (145)
```

My gatsby-config.js is:

```
    module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Plat`,
    description: `We build tools.`,
    author: `@plat`,
    // siteUrl:`https://www.coolsite.org`
    siteUrl:`https://www.coolsite.org`
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `pdf`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pdf`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
      options: {
        // The option defaults to true
        checkSupportedExtensions: false,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/favicon.png`, 
      },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-postcss',
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-strapi`,
      options: {
        apiURL:`https://mydigitaloceanserver.app`,
        //apiURL: `http://localhost:1337`,
        queryLimit: 5000,
        contentTypes: [`post`, `category`,`user`,`tag`,`page`],
        singleTypes: [`homepage`,`about`],    
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        // CommonMark mode (default: true)
        commonmark: true,
        // Footnotes mode (default: true)
        footnotes: true,
        // Pedantic mode (default: true)
        pedantic: true,
        // GitHub Flavored Markdown mode (default: true)
        gfm: true,
        // Plugins configs
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: `@raae/gatsby-remark-oembed`,
            options: {
              // usePrefix defaults to false
              // usePrefix: true is the same as ["oembed"]
              usePrefix: ["oembed", "video","embed","script"],
              providers: {
                include: [
                  'Twitter',
                  'Instagram',
                  'Youtube',
                  'Vimeo',
                  'Codesanbox'
                ],
                exclude: ["Reddit"]
              }
            }
          }
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-stripe`,
      options: {
        objects: ['Product','Sku','Subscription', 'Price', 'Customer'],
        secretKey: process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY,
        downloadFiles: true,
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
      options: {
     
        // Exclude specific pages or groups of pages using glob parameters
        // See: https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch
        // The example below will exclude the single `path/to/page` and all routes beginning with `category`
        exclude: [`/app/*`],
        query: `
          {
            site {
              siteMetadata {
                siteUrl
              }
            }
  
            allSitePage {
              nodes {
                path
              }
            }
        }`,
        resolveSiteUrl: ({site}) => {
          //Alternatively, you may also pass in an environment variable (or any location) at the beginning of your `gatsby-config.js`.
          return site.siteMetadata.siteUrl
        },
        serialize: ({ site, allSitePage }) =>
          allSitePage.nodes.map(node => {
            return {
              url: `${site.siteMetadata.siteUrl}${node.path}`,
              changefreq: `daily`,
              priority: 0.7,
            }
          })
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-robots-txt',
      options: {
        host: 'https://www.platformable.com',
        sitemap: 'https://www.coolsite.org/sitemap.xml',
        policy: [{ userAgent: '*', allow: '/',disallow: ['/app','/app/*'] }]
      }
    },
    
  ],

and this is my gatsby-node.js 

    const path = require(`path`);
    require("dotenv").config({
      path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
    })
    
    const makeRequest = (graphql, request) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Query for nodes to use in creating pages.
      resolve(
        graphql(request).then(result => {
          if (result.errors) {
            reject(result.errors)
          }
          return result;
        })
      )
    });
    
    // Implement the Gatsby API “createPages”. This is called once the
    // data layer is bootstrapped to let plugins create pages from data.
    exports.createPages = ({ actions, graphql }) => {
      
      const { createPage } = actions;
      
      const getPosts = makeRequest(graphql, `
        {
          allStrapiPost {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                title
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        }
        `).then(result => {
        // Create pages for each article.
        result.data.allStrapiPost.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
          createPage({
            path: `/${node.slug}`,
            component: path.resolve(`src/templates/blog-post.js`),
            context: {
              slug:node.slug
            },
          })
        })
      });
      
      // Query for articles nodes to use in creating pages.
      return getPosts;
    };
    
    exports.sourceNodes = ({actions})=> {
      const {createTypes} = actions;
      const typeDefs = `
      type StrapiAbout implements Node {
        content: String 
      }
    
      type StrapiPost implements Node {
        slug: String
      } 
      `
    
      createTypes(typeDefs);
    }
    
    
    // Implement the Gatsby API “onCreatePage”. This is
    // called after every page is created.
    exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
      const { createPage } = actions
      // Only update the `/app` page.
      if (page.path.match(/^\/app/)) {
        // page.matchPath is a special key that's used for matching pages
        // with corresponding routes only on the client.
        page.matchPath = "/app/*"
        // Update the page.
        createPage(page)
      }
    }
```

Im only having this issue on DigitalOcean. When deploying on Vercel or Netlify it works ok.

am i missing something?

Answer (score 3):

There are a lack of details or implementations but, if it works properly on other CD tools, it seems that there's a mismatching of Node versions between environments.

Normally (in Netlify for instance) you can set a `.nvmrc` file in the root of the project with simply the Node version in it and, during the deployment, the CI tool takes that version to install dependencies.

In DigitalOcean it seems that you need to set it using the `package.json` like:

```
{ 
  "engines" : { 
    "node" : "12.19.0" 
  }
}
```

Check the Node version by `node -v` and set properly the `engines` to force DigitalOcean to install the dependencies for a specific Node version.

In addition, try changing `checkSupportedExtensions` to its default value:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
  options: {
    // The option defaults to true
    checkSupportedExtensions: true,
  },
},
```

Comment: HI, thanks for your response. i have checked my node version and it is 14.16.1, i have added the engines with that version and still fails.

Comment: What about `checkSupportedExtensions: true,`

Comment: Thanks, changing checkSupportedExtensions: false to true worked, Its weird because its supposed to be true as default.  Thanks!

Comment: Just added a new page and now its not working again. Something weird on DigitalOcean

Comment: Can you provide more details? Have you checked https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/deploying-to-digitalocean-droplet/  or https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-gatsby-application-to-digitalocean-app-platform ?

Comment: Yes i checked that info, i think is related to gatsby-image plugin, just updated it and deploy worked. going to read about the migration to gatsby-plugin-image that i already did but must be missing something. Will let you know